# 404 error when spring security is added in the web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to use Spring Security but I'm getting 404 error in the `web.xml` page after adding spring security tag in the web.xml page. If I remove the security tags in the web.xml then the .jsp pages are running the local host. I am unable to figure out the problem in the tags in the web.xml. Please help me in finding the problem. I have given all the XML codes.

Below is my code snippet from my project.

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- changed -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my `dispatcher.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context      
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">


    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.springMvc"></ctx:component-scan> 
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.springSecurity"></ctx:component-scan>


</beans:beans>
```

The spring security xml is given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context      
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/helloSecurity*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="sjit" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service> 
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: How you can get _404 error in the web.xml page_? It is not page - it is configuration file. Can you provide stack trace and how you invoke trouble? Show us `spring-security.xml`

Comment: @Optio I have given the code.

Comment: in what moment do you receive 404? What are you doing for this? If you try to open some page - please provide us uri to this page.

Comment: http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/homeSecurity.jsp .... I have configured tomcat to 9090 and this is the url...whatever page I'm trying to open it's giving me 404